# Python Subprocess.Popen doesn't run the Process

Tags: python, subprocess, executable

Hello im trying to open an process via python.

If i was using `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.check_call` it worked as i expected.

The only problem is my program stops working even if the executed process is fully "booted".

with `process.Popen` its just dont work, how can i get `process.Popen` running?

```
clientPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SomeFolder\\SomeExecutable.exe"
subprocess.Popen(clientPath, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

That doesn't work for me

Couldn't find help in other questions.

Comment: How do you know the subprocess doesn't run?

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.Popen should give you a result back, the process handle.
Try adding changing code to

```
clientPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SomeFolder\\SomeExecutable.exe"
process = subprocess.Popen(clientPath, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print('Process ID', process)
print('Is Process alive', process.poll())
```

As a good alternative, you could use a subprocess wrapper, ie `command_runner`

Install with `pip install command_runner`

Run with

```
from command_runner import command_runner

cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\SomeExecutable.exe"
exit_code, output = command_runner(cmd)
print(exit_code)
print(output)
```

Then you can make sure your program won't run too long to make sure your program won't block somewhere:

```
exit_code, output = command_runner(cmd, timeout=300)
```